# Strange issue with stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, ibm-midrange, iseries-navigator

I am having a strange issue with a stored procedure where a variable ErrMsg in below just does not seem to be getting initialized. Tried debugging and it just has a value of null and the assignment operation simply doesn't seem to work??

B

Comment: god knows what the issue was but i changed the decalration to Declare ErrMsg Char(128) Default '';    with a default value and seems to be working now

Comment: declare x1 char(2);  set x1 = '  ';  for some reason I specifically set values.  Probably that null thing was happening at one time.   God is capitalized.

Comment: Sorry Danny I did not understand that

Comment: do you have some duplicated lines in the source? Check the cursor declaration, and the merge.

Comment: No Murph,, no duplicated lines.. I think the issue is because if the first validation i use fails, Set ErrMsg = '-Group ID Not Active-'; will be executed and if there are further failures, the error messages will append succesfully. But if the first validation does not fail, the rest of the validations if they fail, concatenate the error message... Set ErrMsg = Trim(ErrMsg) ||'-Discount Quarter Not Valid-'; So this will be like doing Trim operation on a NULL which does not seem to work. But initializing the ErrMsg field with '' will ensure no  nulls. What do you think?

Comment: I just never use the default keyword on a declare statement.

Comment: If ErrMsg is never initialized (e.g., no default), then TRIM(ErrMsg) may give unpredictable results. NULL is a definite possibility.